# span tag not working in online name checking using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Here is my code in JavaScript that is calling **check.php** file for checking online existence of user in the database

```
<html>

    <input type = "text" name="txt1" id="user" onKeyUp="check_username(this.value)"> <br>

<script>

    var xmlhttp = false;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    function check_username(str) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var arr = xmlhttp.responseText.split("^");
                document.getElementById("user").value = arr[1];

                if (arr[0] == 1) {
                    </script>
                    <span style="color:blue">Username exists</span>
                    <script>
                } else {
                </script>
                    <span style="color:green">user available</span>
                    <script>
                }
            }
            }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "check.php?txt1="+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>

</html>
```

And below is **check.php** file

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("check");

    $username = ($_REQUEST['txt1']);
    $a = 0;
    if (checkexistence($username)) {
        $a = 1;
        echo $a."^".$username;
    } else {
        $a = 0;
        echo $a."^".$username;
    }

    function checkexistence($username) {
        $check = mysql_query("select uname from t1");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
            if (strcmp($username, $row['uname']) == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
   }
?>
```

It works correctly when I use **alert** (of course, we cannot use alert as it will become too irritating) but when I am using **span tag** it do not works correctly giving only

> Username exists user available

as output instead of checking after each character we enter in the textfield..

How can I correct it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't close and open the scripts in between of `if` `else` statements.

You can achieve this using `jQuery` library in easily. Download the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/download/) from here. You can include this `jQuery` files in bottom of the page, like this

```
<script src="js/jquery.1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Let's do that in different way of manner. Use `jQuery` method of [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert a content in between any where.

And try this code,

```
<input type = "text" name="txt1" id="user" onKeyUp="check_username(this.value)"> <br>
<span id="exist" style='color:blue'></span>
<span id="avail" style='color:green'></span>
<script>

    var xmlhttp = false;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    function check_username(str) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var arr = xmlhttp.responseText.split("^");
                document.getElementById("user").value = arr[1];

                if (arr[0] == 1) {
                    $("#avail").html();
                    $("#exist").html('Username exists');
                } else {
                    $("#exist").html();
                    $("#avail").html('User available');
                }
            }
            }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "check.php?txt1="+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55811/discussion-between-sameer-singh-and-ranjith).

Comment: @SameerSingh : I edited my answer. Check it now..
You should add your "<span" directly in html. The "exist" or "available" only added dynamic